# symbolicating crash logs for crashes within the framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I have a created a custom framework with all the code in the framework with the help of [This link](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/). I used this framework in a new project and the code is working fine without any problem. But, the problem is when the app crashes. The crash report just says the app crashed in main. I just wanted to know if there is any way that can point me to the exact location of the crash? ie; if the crash came from within the framework, I need it to point me to the location inside the framework.

**EDIT: Crash Report**

```
Incident Identifier: 6999FFB7-03EC-4A22-B34D-40CD3184AC55
CrashReporter Key:   c6f615ecd88296b5453f757cbd24cc39211bf01c
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         testFramework [11504]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/59004FF6-D0F2-4370-B516-036D02EC223F/testFramework.app/testFramework
Identifier:      testFramework
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  debugserver [11502]

Date/Time:       2013-03-25 17:16:14.597 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3246c29e 0x323aa000 + 795294
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a2c597a 0x3a2bd000 + 35194
2   CoreFoundation                  0x323b7b70 0x323aa000 + 56176
3   testFramework                   0x000e63de 0xe5000 + 5086
4   UIKit                           0x34293590 0x34271000 + 140688
5   UIKit                           0x342d3d74 0x34271000 + 404852
6   UIKit                           0x342cfae8 0x34271000 + 387816
7   UIKit                           0x343111e4 0x34271000 + 655844
8   testFramework                   0x000e6318 0xe5000 + 4888
9   UIKit                           0x342d4ad4 0x34271000 + 408276
10  UIKit                           0x342d465e 0x34271000 + 407134
11  UIKit                           0x342cc846 0x34271000 + 374854
12  UIKit                           0x34274c34 0x34271000 + 15412
13  UIKit                           0x342746c8 0x34271000 + 14024
14  UIKit                           0x34274116 0x34271000 + 12566
15  GraphicsServices                0x35f6859e 0x35f62000 + 26014
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3244167e 0x323aa000 + 620158
17  CoreFoundation                  0x32440ee4 0x323aa000 + 618212
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3243fcb2 0x323aa000 + 613554
19  CoreFoundation                  0x323b2eb8 0x323aa000 + 36536
20  CoreFoundation                  0x323b2d44 0x323aa000 + 36164
21  UIKit                           0x342cb480 0x34271000 + 369792
22  UIKit                           0x342c82fc 0x34271000 + 357116
23  testFramework                   0x000e6156 0xe5000 + 4438
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a6fcb1c 0x3a6fb000 + 6940


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c3350 0x3a7b2000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a73a11e 0x3a70b000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a77696e 0x3a70b000 + 440686
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39d14d4a 0x39d11000 + 15690
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39d11ff4 0x39d11000 + 4084
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a2c5a74 0x3a2bd000 + 35444
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39d12078 0x39d11000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39d12110 0x39d11000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39d13594 0x39d11000 + 9620
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a2c59cc 0x3a2bd000 + 35276
10  CoreFoundation                  0x323b2f1c 0x323aa000 + 36636
11  CoreFoundation                  0x323b2d44 0x323aa000 + 36164
12  UIKit                           0x342cb480 0x34271000 + 369792
13  UIKit                           0x342c82fc 0x34271000 + 357116
14  testFramework                   0x000e6156 0xe5000 + 4438
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a6fcb1c 0x3a6fb000 + 6940

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c3d98 0x3a7b2000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a711cf6 0x3a70b000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a711a12 0x3a70b000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a7118a0 0x3a70b000 + 26784

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7b3648 0x3a7b2000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a6e3974 0x3a6db000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a6e3654 0x3a6db000 + 34388

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7c3d98 0x3a7b2000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a711cf6 0x3a70b000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a711a12 0x3a70b000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a7118a0 0x3a70b000 + 26784

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7b2eb4 0x3a7b2000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a7b3048 0x3a7b2000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32441040 0x323aa000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3243fd9e 0x323aa000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x323b2eb8 0x323aa000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x323b2d44 0x323aa000 + 36164
6   WebCore                         0x38379500 0x3836f000 + 42240
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a71c30e 0x3a70b000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a71c1d4 0x3a70b000 + 70100

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3c2aa534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3c2aab88      r6: 0x1c5338d4      r7: 0x2fd1b9b4
    r8: 0x1c5338b0    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x346eaaa8     r11: 0x3acebd2c
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd1b9a8      lr: 0x3a73a123      pc: 0x3a7c3350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0xe5000 -    0xe6fff +testFramework armv7  <69d86a20d0a4385491aac6ed4668865c> /var/mobile/Applications/59004FF6-D0F2-4370-B516-036D02EC223F/testFramework.app/testFramework
0x2fe33000 - 0x2fe53fff  dyld armv7  <454baf45f9a831aa88e1ea4447c58d4e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31674000 - 0x31674fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31675000 - 0x317b3fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x317b4000 - 0x31897fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31898000 - 0x31b4dfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31b4e000 - 0x31ba7fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31ba8000 - 0x31bb9fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x31bba000 - 0x31bbafff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x320c1000 - 0x32186fff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32187000 - 0x321ddfff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x323aa000 - 0x324dcfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x324dd000 - 0x32615fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32617000 - 0x32652fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32836000 - 0x32851fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32852000 - 0x32907fff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x32995000 - 0x329fafff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32a84000 - 0x32adafff  CoreTelephony armv7  <c5a2e59bb15d35b8a8e356e129b78b5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32adb000 - 0x32b3dfff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32b3e000 - 0x32b4dfff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32cd2000 - 0x32e95fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x33050000 - 0x33099fff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3309a000 - 0x33272fff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33789000 - 0x337e2fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x338d1000 - 0x338d8fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x338da000 - 0x338dafff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x338de000 - 0x338e0fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x338e1000 - 0x338e5fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x338e6000 - 0x33923fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3401e000 - 0x34133fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34182000 - 0x341b0fff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3422f000 - 0x3426efff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x34271000 - 0x347c5fff  UIKit armv7  <e138ca6a809b399691d933dd3d58d00e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x347c6000 - 0x34804fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x34ae5000 - 0x34ae8fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <a2170ad876f13ef1b944547913d05af2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34f14000 - 0x34f4ffff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34fc2000 - 0x34fcbfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34fe5000 - 0x34ffcfff  BackBoardServices armv7  <585cc62d83c530ee82988de940c1e161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x35006000 - 0x3502afff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35260000 - 0x35265fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x3552b000 - 0x3552cfff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35599000 - 0x3559efff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x357c5000 - 0x357defff  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x35851000 - 0x35c64fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35e5c000 - 0x35e68fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35f62000 - 0x35f6dfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x36259000 - 0x362a5fff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x362ac000 - 0x362adfff  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x362ae000 - 0x362b3fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x362b4000 - 0x362b8fff  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36302000 - 0x364a8fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x367a3000 - 0x367d0fff  MobileAsset armv7  <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x36815000 - 0x36818fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <c63e4b1ae40635cd9c6a7de851c80d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x36819000 - 0x3681ffff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3687c000 - 0x3687ffff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x3716c000 - 0x37191fff  OpenCL armv7  <5bf059a9deb632678d70099f14f51b82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x377a5000 - 0x377cdfff  PrintKit armv7  <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x377ce000 - 0x37842fff  ProofReader armv7  <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37987000 - 0x37998fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <e2571f80a0ad3dc580c69794457bd887> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x37b02000 - 0x37b04fff  TCC armv7  <d5bef30a5bda315194173b862975f9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x37b23000 - 0x37b30fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x37fb3000 - 0x38053fff  UIFoundation armv7  <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x3834f000 - 0x3836efff  WebBookmarks armv7  <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3836f000 - 0x38c9efff  WebCore armv7  <ce52fd40ccc236c4b86c020beabb1bb0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x38c9f000 - 0x38d7cfff  WebKit armv7  <dee20c7689bc3e029172b488d8c5f772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x38e27000 - 0x38e2efff  XPCObjects armv7  <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x39b3e000 - 0x39b44fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <f40705b5e9c43ce3b1f185fe690b9ac8> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x39b45000 - 0x39b5bfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39b73000 - 0x39b7ffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <ea41737238273d73b173ec09358d7b62> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x39b91000 - 0x39b91fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x39caf000 - 0x39cbbfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x39cbc000 - 0x39cc5fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <b04d27fa0f2d31d8bd0745f8aa0d7f67> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x39cc6000 - 0x39d10fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ceb9fb64fb203d3a94063a9db6590ca4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x39d11000 - 0x39d24fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x39d55000 - 0x39e42fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ac23bb84e91e35418c9a2fb4792658b2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x39e43000 - 0x39f8cfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <da9d04cc6f6d3825aa52636342ef1e04> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x39f94000 - 0x39f94fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a10d8f96815d35e0a1d2c7b998a941f3> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x39f97000 - 0x39f9efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <996afbc31d8b3f2a907be2427509a4c8> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3a2bd000 - 0x3a3bbfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3a47f000 - 0x3a494fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <3ee61a04a99b322e97e179bc03c46cf1> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3a4b9000 - 0x3a53efff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cbefd01867b93d2a869a534825a1414c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3a53f000 - 0x3a58afff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e3154b06ac5d360c948111abfb2bc339> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3a58b000 - 0x3a5b1fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <c43990ee3a5e389aacf288c3615a50dc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3a5b5000 - 0x3a662fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <28dcf6ee713b387ebb763d11d4b3cd37> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3a663000 - 0x3a683fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <d327d9e0f43333568abda8d83558c8a9> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3a684000 - 0x3a690fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <3ea49513bc023326be68e35324c11d0e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3a691000 - 0x3a694fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <91862e82d5063531b4fb4da9a19e5365> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3a695000 - 0x3a69bfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <d9e66574881739e8b25c3ae087a9f409> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3a69c000 - 0x3a69efff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <6ac449c92d743640a23d9d1ebe0b48a9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3a69f000 - 0x3a6a4fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <87bcae8743ab35c8a070ac95b7d57acb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3a6a5000 - 0x3a6dafff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <04b464137fc2304b84eeed1a5418f4a8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3a6db000 - 0x3a6f8fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9323bb560d4e3a3fb41efdc78bd0cf94> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3a6f9000 - 0x3a6fafff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <c25502085c833181b2a12cf525cffde6> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3a6fb000 - 0x3a6fcfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <82229500ed4132ecbe012e0774e5fc4a> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3a6fd000 - 0x3a6fdfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <e19c865e73e2352bbc8022033e953f22> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3a6fe000 - 0x3a703fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <c8bedc36bc3d3b55b91b12ebb1240968> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3a704000 - 0x3a707fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <965ab939e24935e7a3a65981574a7745> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3a708000 - 0x3a709fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <295706037a5238b4aa145df7b9354a0e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3a70a000 - 0x3a70afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <50a01a02f573317fbd21e1070b0afc7d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3a70b000 - 0x3a791fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <cacc68d271e53338b7780c26f651b767> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3a792000 - 0x3a798fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c5ac17133a1366aaeea5dc38dceaf1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3a799000 - 0x3a7b1fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <5a4a4c9da868317db7f17cb616eb32d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3a7b2000 - 0x3a7c8fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <8e995919df713a8783f23e7f6649bf09> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3a7c9000 - 0x3a7e5fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <036ea0321da038e8b69a0c4413da00fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3a7e6000 - 0x3a7f4fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <afc167a2e9be3dd6851da8deaf42bafd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3a7f5000 - 0x3a7fcfff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <c1d71aa978383c51a9ba2b32782d6cc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3a7fd000 - 0x3a7fefff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <45bb99d46408351a9c61b5326032adea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3a7ff000 - 0x3a7fffff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <df8f1d90cbb837cc92d5901fab94e6ca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3a800000 - 0x3a815fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7f983066ea4c3c119f3e2344a04fef6e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: Please add an example crash report! This does not have to be related to using a framework this is in fact a static library. Without an example all you can get are basically assumptions.

Comment: @Kerni I have added the crash report. this was a deliberate crash and must show array out of bounds error. could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a crash caused by an exception. Since exceptions get rethrown into another runloop, the main thread 0 will always only show `main.m`. So the real location where the crash occured is then shown in the `Last Exception Backtrace`.

You would of course need to symbolicate the pasted crash report and would then see the details in there.

One hint: you should **NOT** strip the debug symbols from the static library that is used in the faked framework. Otherwise the crash reports will never show the line of code where the crash occurred.

Check that the static library target has the following build settings (should be identical in your app):

- Strip Debug Symbols During Copy: No
- Strip Linked Product: No
- Deployment Postprocessing: No
- Generate Debug Symbols: Yes